# using drawnow: Interrupt while evaluating uicontrol Callback

Tags: matlab, callback, while-loop, switch-statement

I have a problem with a while loop inside a switch-case statement, used together with callback functions and "drawnow". In my code, while the cases of the switch-case are determined by pushbuttons in uicontrol, the case statements involves further callback functions to track mouse movements using 'windowbuttondown/up/motionfcn's. Because I draw multiple plots inside the while loop in the case statement, however, I use 'drawnow', which gives me the following error when I run the programme:

Error on line 160 ==> drawnow
??? Interrupt while evaluating uicontrol Callback

The piece of code inside the case statement gives no error when I run independently but somehow creates problem when is integrated with the rest of the code, which I attach below. Any help would be so much appreciated. Many thanks!

```
function programme(selection)

if nargin == 0 
selection=0
end

switch selection
case 0 %start GUI and uicontrols to set up the cases i.e programme(1), programme(2) etc         
    uicontrol('style','pushbutton',...
        'string','First', ...
        'position',[50 700 50 20], ...
        'callback','programme(1);');
    uicontrol('style','pushbutton',...
        'string','Second', ...
        'position',[150 700 50 20], ...
        'callback','programme(2);');

case 1

    %mouse track:
    set(gcf,'windowbuttondownfcn','mousedown=1;');
    set(gcf,'windowbuttonupfcn','mouseup=1;');
    set(gcf,'windowbuttonmotionfcn','mousemotion=1;');

    %to terminate the while loop, set up stopit=1 on one of uicontrol buttons:   
    uicontrol('style','pushbutton',...
        'string','First', ...
        'position',[50 700 50 20], ...
        'callback','stopit=1;');

    stopit=0;

    while (stopit==0)
        if mousedown==1
            statements   
            if mouseup ==1
                statements (plots)
                mouseup=0;
                mousedown=0;
                mousedown=0;
            end
        end
        drawnow
    end

case 2
    statements
otherwise
    statements
```

end

Answer (score 1):

Look in the help: [drawnow](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/drawnow.html)
It interrupts callbacks. And you call your function in a callback. Maybe you can replace it with a `pause(0.01)`.

Though I would strongly advise you to get rid of the loop and use callbacks instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the comment! Unfortunately, pause(0.01) gives the very same error, too. I've been trying to find a way to get rid of the while loop, but then I do not know exactly how. In the code above, the GUI user can interactively bend the lines on the plot until they press a stop button. The case options selects different regions on the plot. I am not sure 2 nested switch-case arguments (one for the region select, the other for the mousetrack) would be efficient and applicable. Could you please give me some further advice? I have to use drawnow to update Figure on each iteration.

Comment: Actually you don't need drawnow. Matlab will redraw when it finds time. drawnow tells it to interrupt all the background stuff and "draw now". Unfortunately your callback function is one of the background stuff. Your problem is that the while loop "blocks" drawing and drawnow breaks the loop. You will need to formulate your program different.